# Issues in state management and loading the data

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I'm trying to load User data in a profile screen but I got an error screen that the data is null but when I make an hot reload with "r" I got the screen right as it should be. I think it's an issue with the way I'm loading data or my management of state.

```
_loadPage() async {
 setState(() {
  isLoading = true;
 });
 _sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 _userData= _sharedPreferences.getString("user_details");
 currentUser = new User.fromJSON(json.decode(_userData));
 setState(() {
  isLoading = false;
 });
}

@override
void initState() {
 _loadPage();
 super.initState();
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
 body: new CustomScrollView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  slivers: <Widget>[
   new SliverPadding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        sliver: new SliverList(
          delegate: new SliverChildListDelegate(
            <Widget>[

              new Column(
                children: <Widget>[

                  new Center(
                    child: new Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[

                        new CircleAvatar(
                           backgroundImage: currentUser?.profilUrl == null
                              ? new 
                           AssetImage("assets/icons/android/picture.jpg")
                              : new NetworkImage(
                              currentUser?.profilUrl),
                           maxRadius: 70.0,
                          minRadius: 50.0,
                        ),
                        new Text(
                          currentUser.name.toString(),
                        ),
                        new Text(
                          currentUser.email,
                        ),
                     ),
                  ),
                 ),
                ],
               ),
              ),

  ],
 ),
);
```

I got those values pictures, text and email like that. But it's Showing this error when I run the app in terminal.

```
I/flutter (29402): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE 
 ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (29402): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling 
a gesture:
I/flutter (29402): The getter 'content' was called on null.
I/flutter (29402): Receiver: null
I/flutter (29402): Tried calling: content
```

Comment: Your title and content don't really match. In one you talk about handling error in parsing and the other you talk about state management and hot reload.

Comment: Where are you getting null

Comment: Getting null from currentUser.name but when you make the hot reload it doesn't show null again.

Comment: please post the entire class as this doesn't give us enough information

Comment: Thanky you and I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

json is asynchrone, use await and CircularProgressIndicator when isLoading is true.